# Lenovo ThinkPad T470 Not Reading Samsung SSD Windows 10 Pro with BitLocker

Tags: windows-10, ssd, thinkpad, bitlocker

My ThinkPad T470 Windows 10 Pro laptop suddenly stopped being able read and boot Win10 from its Samsung 970 EVO Plus SSD.  The SSD has BitLocker enabled.

Lenovo Diagnostics show the SSD's read tests failed.  Using partition recovery software (Lazesoft) shows the drive as unformatted.  I've toggled the BIOS's Secure Boot and Security Chip options.

Using Windows Recovery Environment, I can view all the files on the SSD from the command line.

**How can I get the laptop to boot the operating system again?**

Comment: Lazesoft Shows the drive as unformatted due to the fact you’re using BitLocker. You should be able to disable BitLocker from WinRE, however, in my experience Windows becomes unbootable only because of corrupted system files typically caused by hardware failure

Comment: Entering `manage-bde -protectors -disable C: -rebootcount 0` to disable BitLocker returns "The drive specified is not the operating system drive." Running `DiskPart` failed to clear the SSD's read-only setting so I haven't been able to run `CHKDSK` commands to confirm hardware failure.  Is there (1) a way to have BitLocker recognize the drive as the operating system or an alternate way to disable BitLocker and (2) a command line command (or bootable USB software) to test whether the SSD is corrupted?  Will changing BIOS settings have any effect?

Comment: manage-bde -protectors -disable is the only way to disable BitLocker outside of Windows